# User can't access SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

We have one SSRS 2005 report website. And there is one user, who can access the web for long time. But one day, he can't access the website. His IE browser shows the web can't be open.
I am the admin of the SSRS report website. I have set the user the account to the database where the SSRS reports locate. I even set this user one admin account for the server. But the user can't access the SSRS website anyway.

Could some one please help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Four levels to SSRS:

1. User Type: 'Admin' or 'Quest'
2. Folder permission on url at http:// (reportserver)/Reports.  Hit Folders ensure user is set up there with their credentials.
3. Reports use either embedded credentials or a windows user authenticating to the report.
4. If browser is not working was it upgraded from IE 6 or older to newer?  You may have to add the site to trusted sites.